# ¿Como cambiar el tipo de dato en una función en c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

Buen día a todos, quiero cambiar el tipo de dato de string a datetime, pero me sale el error `No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'string' en 'System.DateTime'`

Así es como lo hice

```
    public static DateTime validarFecha(string value, DateTime defaultValue)
    {
        DateTime dtFechaNacimiento;
        try
        {
            dtFechaNacimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
            return value;
        }
        catch
        {
            value = "01/01/1900";
            dtFechaNacimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Intenté también hacerlo de esta manera pero sigue el mismo error

```
    public static DateTime validateDatetime(string value, DateTime defaultValue)
    {
        DateTime dtFechaNacimiento;
        try
        {
            dtFechaNacimiento = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return value;
        }
        catch
        {
            value = "01/01/1900";
            dtFechaNacimiento = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return value;
        }
    }
```

¿Cual es mi problema aquí? Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: no puedes hacer esto: `return value;` ya que estas retornando el mismo valor que estas recibiendo, debes retornar `dtFechaNacimiento` en tu caso, y esto: `dtFechaNacimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(value);` puede darte un error si el `value` no tiene el formato correcto para fecha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es porque devuelves "value", tienes que devolver dtFechaNacimiento.

Especificas que la función va a devolver un DateTime, pero despues de hacer la conversion intentas devolver el string, no el DateTime.

Te pongo el código en versión reducida:

```
        public static DateTime validateDatetime(string value)
        {
            try
            {
                return DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch
            {
                return DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/1900", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
```

Comment: el problema es que cuando uso la función `linea.Fecha_nacimiento = functions.validateDatetime(linea.Fecha_nacimiento);` Me sale el error `No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.DateTime' en 'string'` :(

Comment: La propiedad linea.Fecha_nacimiento es DateTime o string? Porque ahi te dice que no puede convertir de DateTime a string, como si intentaras meter el retorno de la funcion que es un datetime en una variable string.

Comment: Es string, por eso intento cambiarla en la función

Comment: @Danielle `linea.Fecha_nacimiento = functions.validateDatetime(linea.Fecha_nacimiento)` esto esta mal, estas intentando asignar a `linea.Fecha_nacimiento` el mismo valor que conviertes, es decir esa variable la estas convirtiendo y se la estas asignando a ella misma, por eso te causa el problema, **Utilizando este mismo método de @Mulflar hazlo de esta manera: `Datetime ValorNuevo = functions.validateDatetime(linea.Fecha_nacimiento);` no deberías tener problemas.** Esta variable `linea.Fecha_nacimiento` es de tipo `String` por esto al intentar asignar el valor `DateTime` te presenta ese error.

Comment: Muchas gracias!